# ezjail-admin update -i can't create tank/ezjail/basejail

Tags: freebsd, zfs, update, bsd

I updated the server FreeBSD 8.2-p10 amd64 to 9.1-p1 amd64, and I want to update jails started ezjail. I downloaded the source, built the world and run the command:

```
ezjail-admin update -i
```

but got the message:

```
can't create tank/ezjail/basejail dataset exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

I can remove the `tank/ezjail/basejail`, but it will complicate the ability to roll back to the old version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System looked frozen, but the script worked - the end of the script took a long time (about 4 minutes on 8 core server), after which the script is resumed and update was successful